# (HY000/2002): Operation timed out in macOS

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning to connect to sql databases using php:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF8OvnCBlEY1bFcTW9JKKO7WJn_Bf9LZ1

But the connection is not made, and the error code is:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Operation timed out in /Users/Ahmead/Sites/PHPTest/myTutorials/dbconnect.php on line 12
cannot connect to database fileld:Operation timed out
```

myCode php:

```
  <?php

$host="172.0.0.1";
$user="root";
$password="";
$database="admins";

$connect= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

  if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
      die("cannot connect to database fileld:". mysqli_connect_error());
  }
 else {
      echo 'Database is connected'; 
}

  ?>
```

Comment: How are you running mysql? If localhost - try 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: @KenLee sudo: ufw: command not found

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you, I'm fine, I'm using 127.0.0.1

Comment: Does that mean it works?  Or have you tried it and it still doesn't work?

Comment: @NigelRen I installed mysql-8.0.31 and it works ( indicated in green )

Comment: @NigelRen The site is working, but cannot connect to the database

Comment: @KenLee Thanks, how do I know that?

Comment: I posted the original comment as your code has 172.0.0.1

Comment: @KenLee In the file: php.ini.default, the port is: mysqli.default_port = 3306

Comment: @KenLee Yes host is 127.0.0.1

Comment: @KenLee Thank you, I used my address and this message appeared: `(HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.xx.xx.x' (using password: YES) in`

Comment: @NigelRen  I'm sorry if I bothered you , I used my address and this message appeared: `(HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.xx.xx.x' (using password: YES) in`